# AWS EC2 userdata encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, private-key, user-data

We have usecase of taking input which includes password from user and pass it to on EC2 instance. From with in Ec2 instance we hit the URL - http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/ and get the userdata and set appropriate passwords.

The issue is user data is visible by AWS CLI tool:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id --attribute userData --output text --query "UserData.Value" | base64 --decode
```

This imposes huge security risk.

Whats the best way to send sensitive / secret data ?

I tried creating a key-pair, which creates the private key on local instance and public key on EC2. What would be right way to encrypt / decrypt using PowerShell and fetch it back in EC2?

Answer (score 4):

The suggested approach would be to store any secrets in an external source.

AWS has a service for storing secrets, [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/). By using this service you would create a secret containing the secrets that your instance will need to access in its user data. Then give your instance an IAM role with privileges to get the secret value, [via the AWS CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/secretsmanager/get-secret-value.html).

Alternatively you could also make use of the [AWS SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) service, storing the secrets as a [SecureString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-securestring.html) type. This would work similar to secrets manager with you retrieving the secret [via the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameter.html) and then using it in your script.

There are also third party solutions such as [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) that provide similar functionality if you do not want to store your secrets in an AWS solution.